Travel to Punta Cana as non EU citizen with Permesso di Soggiorno. What else is needed?
May a Moldovan citizen with Italian Permesso di Soggiorno travel to Punta Cana? What documents are needed?

@DavidRecallsMonica doesn’t the Permesso count as a “visa or residence permit” for this purpose?

What type of Permesso di Sogiorno do you have?

As the holder of a permesso, you are exempt from the requirement to have a visa from the Dominican Republic government. However, if your flight itinerary will stop or layover in another country or countries on your way to (or from) the DR, you may need a visa for that interim country or countries. If you do not have it, the airline won't allow you to board. Without itinerary information (airlines, layover durations, and airport names) your question cannot be answered. Please edit your question (using the "Edit" button below the question text) to add this information into your question.

In particular, you'll need a C visa (or B) visa if you have to go through the US, which seems likely.  There's no exemption for any sort of non-US visa or residence permit; it depends solely on citizenship.
